# Wordpress Home/Front Page Display at top of Admin Pages List

Tags: admin

I know this example doesn't show a lot of pages. But, on sites with dozens of pages, I have to go to the next page, scroll, sort by title, etc. to find the home page. Is there a way to have the home/front page always appear at the top of the list.

[image]

Comment: The different columns can be clicked to sort by column, which greatly complicates what you mean by appearing first, as you'd have to account for every single sort, and then again for descending/ascending. Are you sure you wouldn't prefer to get rid of the page and just use the standard `home.php` theme template?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is!! 
If you hover over a page and click "Quick Edit" you will see a box that says "Order", set this to 0, then on the page you want to display next set it to 1. Then on the page you want to display third set it to 2.....etc

Comment: I tried setting home to 1, but it puts it at the very bottom (I'm assuming because all the others default to 0). This doesn't make sense because the number of pages will grow. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yes its because pages default to 0. That's just how it works. It's up to you to keep it organised.

Answer (score 1):

Manually ordering is an option, but `menu_order` is sorted ASC (0 first, then 1, 2, etc). Since Pages default to 0 you'd have to update all other Pages to menu_order 1+ to make your Front page go to the top. This may also have an impact elsewhere on your site, since `menu_order` is used fairly often.

To put both/either of the Static Pages first on the Admin edit Pages section, I made this quick snippet which you can place in your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
// Push Front Page & Posts Page to top of admin list
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'ezific_admin_static_pages_first', 10,2);
function ezific_admin_static_pages_first($orderby, $query) {
    // Leave if not Admin edit Pages query
    if (!( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && 'page' == $query->get( 'post_type' ) ))
        return $orderby;
    // Leave if neither static pages are set
    $front  = (int) get_option( 'page_on_front' );
    $posts  = (int) get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
    $ids    = implode(',', array_filter(array($posts,$front)));
    if ( empty($ids) )
        return $orderby;
    // Update the query
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby = 'FIELD('. $wpdb->posts.'.ID,' .$ids. ') DESC, ' . $orderby;
    return $orderby;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have suggested, you can use the order value.  Set the homepage to -1 and providing no other pages have an order that is the same (or lower), your homepage will always be at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - Pins the Front Page / Homepage to the top if the list using the -1 ordering mentioned above.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| :: UPDATE PAGE ORDER
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Pin Home Page to the top of the list
|
*/
function set_front_page_order() {
  // Get the ID of the front page
  $front_page_id = get_option('page_on_front');

  // Check if the front page ID is set
  if ($front_page_id) {
      // Set the order to -1 for the front page
      $page_data = array(
          'ID'          => $front_page_id,
          'menu_order'  => -1,
      );

      // Update the post with the new menu order
      wp_update_post($page_data);
  }
}

// Hook the function to the 'init' action, so it runs during the initialization of WordPress
add_action('init', 'set_front_page_order');
```

Comment: I take it you ran this once and removed it? You don't want to leave that in your site long term else it'll make a database update for every request to your site.